# How can I make text appear on the screen in the game engine when the character enters a certain area?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, scene

I am making a game and I want text to appear when the character enters a invisible cube. I have tried to make a overlay scene, but I can't make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this.

Your scene idea could be implemented as follows:

Cube:

Collision sensor (filter for a property the character has)
AND controller
Scene Actuator Add Overlay -> your scene with text

Remarks:

- ensure the camera of the overlay scene is showing something
- ensure your character can be detected (static objects are not detected!). In doubt enable Game/Show physics Visualization.